# Nativescript/Angular2: inline sourcemap confusion

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to have .map sourceMap files generated when doing a Angular2/Nativescript build.  I recently updated to Nativescript 2.5.1 and it doesn't seem to generate .map files by default anymore.  The last .map files I can see in my project was from three months ago.  When I add sourcemap: true to tsconfig.json I get an error complaining about not being able to generate sourcemap files with inline sourcemap files.  Any idea what this means?  IF there are inline sourcemap files being generated where can I find it?  How can I debug in visual code using inline sourcemap files?

```
my error:

error TS5053: Option 'sourceMap' cannot be specified with option 'inlineSourceMap'.

my tsconfig.json:

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "platforms",
        "**/*.aot.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding `"inlineSourceMap": false,` to your compiler options?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Yes I did but still get the same error...

Comment: why not just have inline map files?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I don't mind as long as I can debug in visual code...  Where do I find the inline sourcemap files?  is it now in the .js files?  As you can see I don't have a clue where the inline code gets added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly a perfect fix, but here's how I got my IDE working with the sourceMaps with nativescript.  Open `node_modules/nativescript-dev-typescript/lib/compiler.js`.

Change line 33 from:

`nodeArgs.push('--inlineSourceMap', '--inlineSources');`

to

`nodeArgs.push('--sourceMap', '--inlineSources');`.

Running your project you should now have the sourcMapping working as hoped!